# How do I write the value of a function to a file?

Tags: tikz-pgf, write-file, function

What is the best way to write function values to a file from a tikz/pgf point of view?

I've been using native TeX macros like `\immediate\write\file`, but maybe there's a way at the pgf level to do it at a higher level.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}

\pgfset{
  declare function={
    Ra = 5e-2;
    Rb = 10e-2;
    rho = 50e-9;
    epsilon = 8.854e-12;
    sigma = 0.3e-9;
    f(\r) = (\r < Ra) * rho / (2 * epsilon) * \r
    + and(\r > Ra, \r < Rb) * (rho * Ra^2 / (2 * epsilon) * 1 / \r)
    + (\r > Ra) * (1 / (2 * epsilon) * (rho * Ra^2 + 2 * sigma * Rb) * 1 / \r)
    ;
  }
}


\begin{document}

\newwrite\file
\immediate\openout\file=table.txt

\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu, /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
\foreach \x in {0, 0.01, ..., 0.3}{
    \pgfmathparse{f(\x)}
    \edef\y{\pgfmathresult}

    f(\pgfmathprintnumber\x) = \pgfmathprintnumber\y

    % Writing to file
    \immediate\write\file{\x\space\y}
}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}

\immediate\closeout\file

\end{document}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use LaTeX3 functions to open, close and write to text files. But the effort needed would not be much different from that of using TeX macros (that you seem to master already), I guess.

Comment: @AlexG This seems like a crutch to me. Maybe there is some mechanism in pgf. As far as I understand, pgf/pgfplots somehow generates values when plotting. maybe they can be taken.

Comment: Nothing that I know of. Pgfplots has the `pgfplotstable` package for data processing, but it is all about data input (from files).

Comment: What's the motivation for doing this exactly? The reason the package supports input of data files is to offload data processing to tools better able to handle it, so I'm wondering what the use case for doing only the calculations in PGF could be.